# How to write function in .zsh profile that returns cURL response?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

At work, I run a command daily to return a specific token for access to our local repos. It's not a big deal, but I was trying to figure out a faster way of generating this token. Usually, I paste it into VSCode and run a Send Request via the [REST Client Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client).

I'm trying to create a function in my .zsh profile that can then be run in my command line instead. Here's what I currently have:

```
generateToken() {
    response=curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "service-token: xxxx" -X POST -d '{"user": "me.myself@xxxxxxx.com"}' <the-url.com>
    echo "$(response)"
}
```

Then I save, quit, and run `eval ${generateToken}`, but nothing happens. Any suggestions on the best way to get this going?

Comment: Once you've fixed the assignment and output as per the duplicate, you can invoke your function with `generateToken`

Comment: @thatotherguy i've wrapped the curl in parentheses, and fixed the echo statement, however it's just returning the cURL statement rather than the actual response

Comment: I reopened the question. Please update with your code as it is now

Comment: Ah I got it! One of the other popular answers (but below the accepted answer) mentioned the need to wrap in backticks rather than parentheses. This fixed the issue and it's not returning the token correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I think you you cut some corners and used `(..)` instead of `$(..)`. Backticks are a deprecated form that does not use a `$`. Check out [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) which autodetects many such issues.

Comment: You're right, I tried it with `$(..)` and that also works.

Comment: @thatotherguy Shellcheck does not support Zsh

Comment: @shadowtalker True, but the question was originally tagged `bash`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thatotherguy in the comments, I was able to create the following:

```
function generateToken() {
        echo "Generating token..."
        response=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "service-token: xxxxxxx" -X POST -d '{"user": "me.myself@mycompany.com"}' https://api.my.company/token)
        echo "${response}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything to the output, you don't need to capture it and echo it. You can just run the command. It will write its output to the same place that `echo` would if you captured and re-echoed the output.

```
generateToken() {
  echo "Generating token..."
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "service-token: xxxxxxx" \
    -X POST -d '{"user": "me.myself@mycompany.com"}' \
    https://api.my.company/token
}
```